# How do I use a deep copy efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, deep-copy

I am writing a class `GenerateNeighbours` in which an initial solution `Sol` is passed to the constructor. A number of "neighbours" of this solution is to be computed. In order to make sure that my initial solution does not change, I am making a deep copy of the initial solution every iteration.

Also, I am making use of an arraylist `S_Comp` which was created using `generateSComp()`. At the start each iteration, this version of `S_Comp` is to be used. Therefore, I am not calling `generateSComp()` each iteration, as I figured that this would be unnecessary and it would require an excessive amount of time.

Since `S_Comp` changes within each iteration and I want to make sure that I start with the same `S_Comp` each iteration, I am also using a deep copy for this. However, I feel like my approach is not so efficient, since the running time of my program barely improved with respect to calling `generateSComp` every iteration.

Below you can find the code that I am talking about:

```
public GenerateNeighbours(DataFile testDataFile, ArrayList<Route> Sol, Random randomGen) throws IOException
    {       
        solution = (ArrayList<Route>) DeepCopy.copy(Sol);
        S_Comp = new ArrayList<MyNodesData>();
        S_Comp = generateSComp(testDataFile, solution, S_Comp);
        ArrayList<MyNodesData> originalS_Comp = (ArrayList<MyNodesData>) DeepCopy.copy(S_Comp);

        rewards = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        neighbours = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Route>>();

        //---------Generating neighborhood solutions---------
        for(int i=0; i<parameterSet.getBeta(); i++)         
        {
            solution = (ArrayList<Route>) DeepCopy.copy(Sol);      <---- making a deep copy every iteration     
            S_Comp = (ArrayList<MyNodesData>) DeepCopy.copy(originalS_Comp);    <---- making a deep copy every iteration
//          S_Comp = new ArrayList<MyNodesData>();          
//          generateSComp(testDataFile, solution, S_Comp);      <------- This is what should be unnecessary since S_Comp is the same at the start of every iteration 
            step1to6(i);
            rewards.add(getSolutionReward(solution));
            neighbours.add(solution);
        }
    }
```

Since I am making two deep copies every iteration, I feel like my program is rather inefficient. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to use my deep copies more efficiently? Or is this just the way it should be done?

(For the `DeepCopy` class I used the one as suggested at http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/)

Comment: Are you translating some code written in some other language to java? You should not need to do deep copies. Think about the solution afresh.

Comment: @gagansingh I am not translating any code, all code was written in Java. Both `solution` and `S_Comp` are updated in `step1to6()`, which is why in new iterations, the updated values will be used instead of the originals if I do not use copies.